# Who are the eight questers in The Magicians?

Tags: the-magicians

In season 3 episode 12 of The Magicians Quentin says to Alice that there are seven keys and eight questers so if you do not cooperate then also they can manage to complete the quest.Who are the eight persons involved in the quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who are the eight persons involved in the quest?

In no [**particular order**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sa=X&q=Olivia%20Taylor%20Dudley&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLWz9U3MDS2LDOoyFDiAnHSy1KycuO1xLKTrfRLyoAovqAoP70oMdcqObG45BFjMLfAyx_3hKW8Jq05eY3RhQuHQiEtLjbXvJLMkkohBS5-KWR7NBikeLmQBXgA0u4izYkAAAA&npsic=0&ved=0ahUKEwiEs7nanJLaAhXIasAKHdTyCmYQ-BYIJw)...

1. Alice Quinn (played by Olivia Taylor Dudley )
2. Julia Wicker (played by Stella Maeve)
3. Quentin Coldwater (played by Jason Ralph)
4. Eliot Waugh (played by Hale Appleman)
5. Margot Hanson (played by Summer Bishil)
6. Penny Adiyodi (played by Arjun Gupta)
7. Kady Orloff-Diaz (played by Jade Tailor)
8. Josh Hoberman (played by Trevor Einhorn)